# How does the minus minus less than "-->" operator work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
while (max --> min)
{
    console.log(n);
}
```

I know that `-->` decreases the value, but where is `-->` documented in the official documentation?

Comment: it's two things ... post decrement `--` and a greater than comparison `>`

Comment: `-->` is `--` followed by `>`, two operators... So `max-- > min` if you prefer.

Comment: Somebody either slipped on the keyboard or they thought they were being clever…

Comment: @deceze I'd never seen that before, I think it is kinda clever :)! It's like a pun, but with code.

Comment: @judgeja Any cleverness that spawns a question on SO because the reader goes *"WTF?!"* is bad cleverness…

Comment: see also [this highly upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c) (currently the 8th highest upvoted question overall)

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why a single line of JavaScript code starting with '-->' simply does nothing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is the *post decrement operator* `--` followed by the *greater than* operator `>`. Just the spacing is weird.

```
while (max-- > min)
```

So, *while `max` decremented is larger than `min`…*

Comment: Just a nitpick, wouldn't "`max` decremented is larger than `min`" be better suited for something like `--max > min`?

Comment: @Aioros *"`max`'s value which is decremented afterwards is larger than `min`"* seemed a bit unwieldy. I expect everyone knows how `--` works… :)

Comment: would this work in for loop like `for( let i = 0; i++ < n; )`

Comment: Check out this CodeWars kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/6359bf1600fba287b6189f9b/javascript

Apparently, "-->" on its own is a valid piece of JS code.

Comment: P. S. After 5 more minutes of Googling, I now know that due to historical reasons, HTML comments are valid JS code :D